# asp.net web api rest service for multiple platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

can i consume rest service created in web api on multiple platform and is it possible to create a service for file upload and download for multiple platform using web api. 
if possible please provide a sample project.

Comment: ...I suggest you do some research for yourself on this...

Comment: Nope. This is not how you ask questions here. First, you should ask one coherent question when you post, not multiple questions in the same post. Second, you can't just ask for an entire project. If you want sample project code, then do your own research.

Comment: man, you guys dont have to rip him/her a new one. Be polite about it at least.

Comment: @user516883 there has to be a line at which a community steps up and says in no uncertain terms: don't ask this kind of question.  Equally, look at the guy's previous questions... Also this is actually a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978961/wcf-restful-service-file-upload-with-multi-platform-support,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, yes and no.

*Now someone please close this question.*

*Update*

Allow me to explain this answer (before it eventually gets deleted):

It appears that what you're asking is for us to provide a whole solution for you, which is really not what Stack Overflow is for.  Equally, your previous, very similar, question: [WCF Restful service file upload with multi-platform support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978961/wcf-restful-service-file-upload-with-multi-platform-support) is nigh on identical to this one and asked for a similarly large amount of information.

Then there's [How to add wcf service at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874203/how-to-add-wcf-service-at-runtime), which is clearly related, but on which you didn't include any information on what you'd tried...

Questions on stack overflow should include what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and really some code if possible.  And certainly you absolutely should not ask for sample 'projects' - you might get one in response to a question that shows you've put some effort in - but if you do that's a bonus.

In this case I think you should be using google and reading up - here's a link for you: [Asp.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) - you really can't go wrong with that.  I understand that's a link to what you're asking about; but really it's full of tutorials and is the best starting point...